# Sending a file from memory (rather than disk) over HTTP using libcurl

Tags: c++, image, upload, libcurl

I would like to send pictures via a program written in C + +. - OK
It works, but I would like to send the pictures from pre-loaded carrier to a variable char (you know what I mean? First off, I load the pictures into a variable and then send the variable), cause now I have to specify the path of the picture on a disk.

I wanted to write this program in c++ by using the curl library, not through exe. extension.
I have also found such a program (which has been modified by me a bit)

Answer (score 11):

CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS is not the correct usage here, it will not create a file upload part.

Instead one should use [CURLFORM_BUFFER](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html#CURLFORMBUFFER) to send an image from an already existing buffer in memory.

```
 curl_formadd(&formpost,
          &lastptr,
          CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "send",
          CURLFORM_BUFFER, "nowy.jpg",
          CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, data,
          CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, size,
          CURLFORM_END);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the documentation for `curl_formadd`: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html

Specifically, under "Options":

> CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS
>
> followed by a pointer to the contents
>   of this part, the actual data to send
>   away. libcurl will use the pointer and
>   refer to the data in your application,
>   so you must make sure it remains until
>   curl no longer needs it. If the data
>   isn't NUL-terminated, or if you'd like
>   it to contain zero bytes, you must set
>   its length with
>   CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH.
>
> CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH
>
> followed by a long giving the length
>   of the contents. Note that for
>   CURLFORM_STREAM contents, this option
>   is mandatory.

So instead of

```
 curl_formadd(&formpost,
              &lastptr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "send",
              CURLFORM_FILE, "nowy.jpg",
              CURLFORM_END);
```

You'd want something like

```
 curl_formadd(&formpost,
              &lastptr,
              CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "send",
              CURLFORM_PTRCONTENTS, p_jpg_data,
              CURLFORM_CONTENTSLENGTH, jpg_data_len,
              CURLFORM_END);
```

I'm assuming you know how to create `p_jpg_data` and read the data into it, or do you need that explained?