# How to post a buffer as a file using cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using cURL with PHP. I need to post the content of a buffer so that the server sees it as a file upload. This what I tried:

```
$post_data['Filename'] = "foo.wav";

$post_data['File'] =  $filedata;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myurl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

This sends the buffer content as a normal form field and not as a file upload. The examples for uploading a file assume the file was not already read in memory and require the file path to be set with a '@' in front. How can I upload my buffer as though it was a file, without writing my buffer to disk of course?

Comment: It seems the relevant api http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html is not present in the cURL PHP bindings, see for reference a similar question like yours but based on the C api where the functionality is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529357/sending-a-file-from-memory-rather-than-disk-over-http-using-libcurl

Comment: So in PHP it is not possible?